# Is it safe to call revert() instead of returning a value?

Tags: solidity, compiler, exceptions, revert-opcode

I have the following piece of code:

```
function func() public returns (bool) {
    if (some condition on msg.sender) {
        do some stuff
        return true;
    }
    revert();
}
```

The compiler (0.4.24) does not issue any warning about this, even though not all execution paths return a value.

Of course, I could call `revert()` right at the beginning (with an opposite condition) and avoid this issue, but for internal coding-style considerations, I prefer it as shown above.

Now, I know that in C++ for example, a function can throw an exception instead of returning a value and everything remains "in tact". So I suppose that it might be the same here, but I still want to be sure that there is no potential for stack-corruption or something similar (due to the fact that nothing is pushed into the stack when the function terminates).

According to [the docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/assembly.html#opcodes), the `revert` opcode actually does return something.

But I'm not sure if the `revert` **function** does, and even if yes, it wouldn't necessarily be of the same type as in my function (`bool` in this case).

So... do I have anything to worry about here, or does the thrown exception "take care" of the returned value?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Typically `revert` will *bubble-up* and revert the whole transaction so you don't need to worry about incorrect return values - the whole transaction will fail. There is no way to *catch* this kind of exception and therefore no way to prevent it from happening if the code issues a `revert`.

There are some minor exceptions to this rule, namely `delegatecall` and similar functionalities. You can read more about this behaviour (and reverting in general) at: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/control-structures.html#error-handling-assert-require-revert-and-exceptions